# Why does `infix operator $` produce contradictory error messages in Swift?

Tags: swift, operators, dollar-sign

I was having some fun with custom operators, and I had the following code:

```
precedencegroup HaskellGrouping {
    lowerThan: TernaryPrecedence
    associativity: right
}

infix operator $: HaskellGrouping

func $ <T, U>(a: (T) -> U, b: T) -> U {
    return a(b)
}
```

This code produces contradictory error messages:

```
main.swift:6:16: error: '$' is not an identifier; use backticks to escape it
infix operator $ : HaskellGrouping
               ^
               `$`
main.swift:6:16: error: '$' is considered to be an identifier, not an operator
infix operator $ : HaskellGrouping
               ^
main.swift:8:6: error: '$' is not an identifier; use backticks to escape it
func $ <T, U>(a: (T) -> U, b: T) -> U {
     ^
     `$`
compiler exit status 1
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: `Custom operators can begin with one of the ASCII characters /, =, -, +, !, *, %, <, >, &, |, ^, ?, or ~` - from [swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID418). Your custom operator can't start with `$`

Comment: @NewDev Yes, but when I try to use `#`, `:`, `@`, `.`, etc, I get the appropriate error message "expected operator name in operator declaration", not contradictory error messages